# Problems matching VirtualHost for SSL and non-SSL domains

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have a setup of 5 domains. They have a record under `<VirtualHost *:80>` for non-SSL. Each of them have its own record under ex.

```
<VirtualHost 172.30.0.245:443>
 ServerName www.acme.com
 ServerAlias acme.com
```

, because they have different IPs and SSL certificates. This works fine.

I also have a generic record `<VirtualHost *:80>` which is in file 001-vhosts.conf. It catches traffic that is not for my domains. If it doesn't match on some of my domains it returns 410. This also works fine. If I point `http://test.com` to an IP of the server, it goes to the generic record and returns 410.

The problem is when I add a generic record for SSL `<VirtualHost *:443>`. If I open `https://test.com` it matches `<VirtualHost 172.30.0.245:443>` instead of  the generic record. I want traffic for domains that are not mine to return 410 no matter is it on http or https. I use AWS and it is common to have such traffic.

What am I missing?

I have a setup of 5 domains. They have a record under `<VirtualHost *:80>` for non-SSL. Each of them have its own record under ex.

```
<VirtualHost 172.30.0.245:443>
 ServerName www.acme.com
 ServerAlias acme.com
```

, because they have different IPs and SSL certificates. This works fine.

I also have a generic record `<VirtualHost *:80>` which is in file 001-vhosts.conf. It catches traffic that is not for my domains. If it doesn't match on some of my domains it returns 410. This also works fine. If I point `http://test.com` to an IP of the server, it goes to the generic record and returns 410.

The problem is when I add a generic record for SSL `<VirtualHost *:443>`. If I open `https://test.com` it matches `<VirtualHost 172.30.0.245:443>` instead of  the generic record. I want traffic for domains that are not mine to return 410 no matter is it on http or https. I use AWS and it is common to have such traffic.

What am I missing?

The command `sudo apache2ctl -S` returns:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
172.30.0.160:443       www.ssl-domain1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ssl-domain1.conf:121)
172.30.0.139:443       www.ssl-domain2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ssl-domain2.conf:12)
172.30.0.137:443       www.ssl-domain3.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ssl-domain3.conf:7)
172.30.0.245:443       www.ssl-domain4.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ssl-domain4.conf:39)
172.30.0.124:443       www.ssl-domain5.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ssl-domain5.conf:80)
*:443                  ip-172-30-0-73.eu-west-1.compute.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-vhosts.conf:17)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ip-172-30-0-73.eu-west-1.compute.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-vhosts.conf:3)
         port 80 namevhost ip-172-30-0-73.eu-west-1.compute.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-vhosts.conf:3)
         port 80 namevhost acme1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/acme1.com.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost acme2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/acme2.com.conf:3)
                 alias www.acme2.com
                 alias staging.acme2.com
```

Comment: Is the generic `<VirtualHost *:443>` server declared (loaded) before any other HTTPS enabled hosts?

Comment: both generic records for `<VirtualHost *:80>` and <VirtualHost *:443> are in the same file `001-vhosts.conf` in that order. The rest VirtualHosts are in separate file. `001-vhosts.conf` should be loaded last and I think it is working fine as for :80 traffic it does exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: From your question it's not clear to me whether or not you have other vhosts configured on port 80 or just the catch all one?

Comment: I have other vhosts on port 80.

Comment: Why Apache reports `NameVirtualHost *:80` but not `NameVirtualHost *:443`? Strange.